# Is there a reason why Aura Components are still a requirement for the Advanced Apex Superbadge still worth learning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, trailhead, superbadges

I know this has been asked before [Is it worth learning Aura Components?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267589/is-it-worth-learning-aura-components) , but I would like an answer for 2020.

I have been looking at the Advanced Apex Superbadge requirements, and Aura Components Specialist is a prerequisite, which has its own prerequisite badges that appear outdated.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_aap

Is there a reason why this is still a requirement for the Superbadge?  Is it at this level that one is expected to know all possible front-end frameworks?

Comment: IMHO while LWC is a far superior framework, there are things you can do with Aura that you simply can't do with LWC. For example, dynamic creation of components simply by name. Or use of a component as an action. You can find the list of missing capabilities [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/02/working-with-aura-and-lightning-web-components-interoperability-and-migration.html).

Comment: @PhilW , why not put your answer as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Because I'm not sure it really answers the question.

Comment: It sort of does - it at least gives me a good reason why it's still relevant, whether or not that's the reason it's still on trailhead in this fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While LWC is arguably a far superior framework, there are things you can do with Aura that you simply can't do with LWC. For example, dynamic creation of components simply by name. Or use of a component as an action. You can find the list of missing capabilities [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/02/working-with-aura-and-lightning-web-components-interoperability-and-migration.html) (this could be a little out of date since it is a 2019 blog).